# Causes of duplicate results appearing in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-2013

I have a crystal report using the SQL command below.

I am wondering if anyone can assist me with the reason why I am getting duplicate people appearing in my report.

At the moment I get multiple lines for a sales account manager (SAM),
I want one line per SAM.

[image]

My 1st Group Header is based on the Sector Code,
2nd group header is on command.sector,
3rd group header is on SAM

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        'Actuals' as [Trans Type],  
        ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_START_DATE_ISO as [Order Date],
        ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_ENT_DATE_ISO as [Ent Date],
        year(dateadd(month,6,ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_START_DATE_ISO)) as [FYR],
        MONTH(DATEADD(M, 6, ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_START_DATE_ISO)) as [FYP],
        DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_START_DATE_ISO), 0) as [PStart],
        DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_START_DATE_ISO) + 1, 0)) as [Pend],
        Revenue = 
        Case
        When ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_PHASE = '1' and ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_COMPL_STS = 'N'
        then ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_EXT_CHRG 
        When ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_PHASE = '5' and ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_COMPL_STS = 'N'
        then ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_EXT_CHRG 
        Else 0
        End,
        isnull(MM405_USER_NAME,'No SAM') AS [SAM],
        ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_DESC as [Desc], 
        EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_ID as [EventID],
        isnull(SALESACCT.EV870_TYPE,'NoSec') as [Sector],
        isnull(CCRPF_ACCT_TYPE_DESC,'ZZ - No Sector') as [Sector Name],
        EV130_STATUS_MASTER.EV130_STATUS_DESC as [Event Status Desc],
        isnull(EV800_USER_FLD_6X,'N') as [Budgeted]
FROM    ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL WITH (NOLOCK)  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EV700_FUNC_MASTER WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_ORG_CODE = EV700_FUNC_MASTER.EV700_ORG_CODE 
        AND ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_EVT_ID = EV700_FUNC_MASTER.EV700_EVT_ID 
        AND ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_FUNC_ID = EV700_FUNC_MASTER.EV700_FUNC_ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EV800_SPACE_MASTER WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON EV700_FUNC_MASTER.EV700_SPACE = EV800_SPACE_MASTER.EV800_SPACE_CODE 
        AND EV700_FUNC_MASTER.EV700_ORG_CODE = EV800_SPACE_MASTER.EV800_ORG_CODE 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EV200_EVENT_MASTER WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_ORG_CODE = EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE 
        AND ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_EVT_ID = EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EV870_ACCT_MASTER WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE = EV870_ACCT_MASTER.EV870_ORG_CODE
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_SLSPER = EV870_ACCT_MASTER.EV870_ACCT_CODE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EV870_ACCT_MASTER SALESACCT WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_ORG_CODE = SALESACCT.EV870_ORG_CODE
        AND EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_CUST_NBR = SALESACCT.EV870_ACCT_CODE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CCRPF_ACCT_TYPES WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON SALESACCT.EV870_TYPE = CCRPF_ACCT_TYPE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MM405_USER_MASTER_EXT WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON EV870_ACCT_MASTER.EV870_USERID = MM405_USER_MASTER_EXT.MM405_USER_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EV130_STATUS_MASTER WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON EV200_EVENT_MASTER.EV200_EVT_STATUS = EV130_STATUS_MASTER.EV130_STATUS_CODE
       LEFT OUTER JOIN EV370_RES_MASTER WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_ORG_CODE = EV370_RES_MASTER.EV370_ORG_CODE 
       AND ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_NEW_RES_TYPE = EV370_RES_MASTER.EV370_NEW_RES_TYPE 
       AND ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL.ER101_RES_CODE = EV370_RES_MASTER.EV370_RES_CODE
WHERE       EV200_ORG_CODE = '10' and EV200_EVT_STATUS in ('33', '34', '36', '49','50', '52') and NOT(EV200_EVT_TYPE IN ('MOS','MP','GB'))
            and ER101_RES_CLASS <> '8' and ER101_ORD_TYPE = 'SO'
            and not(EV370_RES_MASTER.EV370_MAJOR_GROUP in ('SRVCHR', 'EBOND', 'SCHARG','GIFTC'))

UNION

Select 'Targets' as [Trans Type],   
        MM012_PERIOD_STDATE as [Order Date],
        GL010_ENT_STAMP as [Ent Date],
        MM012_FISCAL_YR as [FYR],
        MM012_FISCAL_PERIOD as [FYP],
        MM012_PERIOD_STDATE as [PStart],
        MM012_PERIOD_ENDATE as [Pend],
        GL010_BUD_PTD as [Revenue],
        'Budget SAM' as [SAM],
        GL010_ACCOUNT as [Desc],    
        null as [Event ID], 
        GL001_SHORT_DESC as [Sector],
        [Sector Name] = 
        Case 
        When CCRPF_ACCT_TYPE_DESC is null then 'OLD - ' + GL001_DESC
        Else CCRPF_ACCT_TYPE_DESC
        End,
        'Budget Event Status Desc' as [Event Status Desc],
        'Targets' as [Budgeted]       
FROM GL010_BALANCES WITH (NOLOCK) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN GL001_ACCOUNT_MASTER
        WITH (NOLOCK) ON GL010_ORG_CODE = GL001_ORG_CODE
        AND GL010_ACCOUNT = GL001_ACCOUNT
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MM012_FISCAL_PERIODS
        WITH (NOLOCK) ON GL010_ORG_CODE = MM012_ORG_CODE
        AND GL010_FISCAL_YR = MM012_FISCAL_YR
        AND GL010_FISCAL_PERIOD = MM012_FISCAL_PERIOD
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CCRPF_ACCT_TYPES
        WITH (NOLOCK) ON GL001_SHORT_DESC = CCRPF_ACCT_TYPE
Where   GL001_ACCT_TYPE = 'SS' and LEFT(GL001_ACCOUNT_MASTER.GL001_ACCOUNT,3)='SEC'
```

Comment: Swap 2nd and 3rd groups... make SAM 2nd group and sector 3rd group

Comment: Thank you. @siva, can you explain what I was doing wrong? I also get quite large gaps between SAM's after this change.

Comment: Each sector has a SAM record so when sector is made a group at level greater than SAM, data for SAM will be splitted for each sector hence you are getting multiple times SAM records, Now when you swap SAM has given higher level to sector, So different sector records are came into SAM and you have only one SAM group. Hope you understood logic. Regarding the gaps, If you can post the image then I will be able to tell the exact reason